# Send a single mail to fundraising responsible

Tags: api, extension, email

I want to send a single mail to a responsible address when a certain event occur in my extension.
I had a look to some API (Email, Mailing, MailingAB) but but none of these seem to be the right one.
There is an API or a class I can use to send mails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Email API extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api) will have example code for you to use for your extension.  Its code is available on github: https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.emailapi

Answer (score 1):

Finally I used the following code for send a mail:

```
    $mailParams = array(
        'groupName' => '...',
        'from' => '...',
        'toName' => '...',
        'toEmail' => '...',
        'subject' =>  '....',
        'text' => ''....,
    );

   $result = CRM_Utils_Mail::send($mailParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the extension [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) that allows you to configure triggers, conditions, and actions such as sending out an email on a certain event.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, I'm writing my own extension, so I would like to send an email regardless of the presence of CiviRules extension.
I looking for a code example, an API or a Class call, usefull for sending a mail.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this extension that Sarah Gladstone wrote. It sounds similar to what you're doing and you might be able to get some example code from it.

https://github.com/sgladstone/com.fountaintribe.scheduledcommunication